# Crystal Reports - Create two Parameters; One parameter (EndDate) = CurrentDate & One parameter (StartDate) = two weeks ago from CurrentDate

Tags: crystal-reports

I have two date parameters ({?StartDate} & {?EndDate}) in my report with default values of 1/9/1900. When refreshed, I have the option to select current parameters values or prompt new values.
Ideally, I would like to distribute the report every two weeks. The data within the report should refresh and contain data from this date range: (day of refresh) to (two weeks ago).

If I am refreshing the report on 8/22/23, {?StartDate} should be 8/8/23 and {?EndDate} should be 8/22/23.

Here is my current formula in Record Selection Formula Editor:

```
If Date(Year({?StartDate}), Month({?StartDate}), Day({?StartDate}) = Date(1900,01,01) and Date(Year({?EndDate}), Month({?EndDate}), Day({?EndDate}) = Date(1900,01,01)
    then 
        {?StartDate} = Date(DateAdd ('d', -14 ,CurrentDateTime))
        {?EndDate} = Date(CurrentDateTime)
    else
        {?StartDate}
        {?EndDate}
```

---

I also tried:

```
DateVar StartDate;
If {?StartDate} = Date('1/1/1900') then
(
  StartDate := DateAdd('d', -14, CurrentDate);
  StartDate := Date(Year(StartDate), Month(StartDate), Day(StartDate);
)
else
  StartDate := {?StartDate};
StartDate 

DateVar EndDate;
If {?EndDate} = Date('1/1/1900') then
(
  EndDate := DateAdd(CurrentDate);
  EndDate := Date(Year(EndDate), Month(EndDate), Day(EndDate);
)
else
  EndDate := {?EndDate};
EndDate
```

---

I run into many errors. Once I fix one error, another error message pops up.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

The one time I didn't have any errors. No data showed on the report and the parameters showed as 1/9/1900 to 1/9/1900.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a value to a parameter in a formula.

Instead, do the comparisons of date logic directly to the relevant database column. For example, the Order_Date.